# Can't load custom PowerShell script from the internet

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download a ps1 script and then execute all in one. It is able to download the ps1 file but then gives me this error. Please help, sorry for all the base64 encryption

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about how to download and without checking anything running a virus script

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrypt this Output with [CyberChef][1], I would not recommend downloading scripts from the internet!

Upload this script to [Virustotal][2] and check it

if you trust the script, check your execution Policy and run it again.

1]: https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/

2]: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/